# C++ destructor called after calling constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, copy-assignment

By looking at the example:

```
#include <iostream>
int wow=0;
class Foo{
   int cow = 0;
public:
  Foo(){
    std::cout << "Foo +\n";
    cow = 0;
    ++wow;
  }
  Foo(int n){
    std::cout << "Foo has " << n << "\n";
    cow = n;
    ++wow;
  }
  ~Foo(){
     std::cout << cow << " ~ Foo -\n";
   }
  void print(){
    std::cout << cow << " is the foo#\n";
  }
};

int main(){
  void * bar = ::operator new(sizeof(Foo));
  Foo * a = new(bar) Foo;
  *a = Foo(10);
  std::cout << wow << std::endl;
  a->~Foo();
  ::operator delete(bar);
  return 0;
}
```

and compiling and running it, the console shows:

```
Foo+
Foo has 10
10 ~ Foo -
2
10 ~ Foo -
```

My question is, why is the destructor called upon calling the constructor?

Should the first destructor call be `0 ~ Foo -` ? Since that is the first Foo
that is overwritten by `Foo(10)`?

Comment: You are not seeing the copy constructors

Comment: how do you compile this? I get some errors https://godbolt.org/z/qM1cj9W3s

Comment: Fixed the `void bar` to `void * bar`, please check @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: Added cow member, I forget about that sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this assignment statement

```
 *a = Foo(10);
```

there is created a temporary object of the type `Foo` that is assigned to the object specified by the expression `*a` using the default copy assignment operator (neither copy or move constructor is called here). After the assignment the temporary object is deleted. The undeclared variable `cow` (it seems it is a data member of the class `Foo`) of the object pointed to by the pointer `a` now contains the same value `10`. And in the end of the program the object pointed to by the pointer `a` is also deleted.

As a result you will get two messages

```
10 ~ Foo -
10 ~ Foo -
```

The first one is generated by the destructor of the temporary object and the second one is generated by the object pointed to by the pointer `a`.

Comment: About "using the default copy assignment operator": shouldn't the default _move_ assignment operator be called here since the argument is a prvalue?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Yes cow is a member of Object Foo. Sorry about that. I already fixed the code.

Comment: Wait I am still confused, how did the temporary `Foo` get the `int cow` to be `10`? When in fact it is the constructor that I call to be `10`?

Comment: Can you make another example please?

Comment: @chi According at least to the C++ 14 Standard if there is user-defined destructor then the move assignment operator is not implicitly declared.

Comment: @itchyfeet You are explicitly call the constructor like Foo(10).